# Copy to Clipboard the entire Selected Row data in TextBox from WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, clipboard

Im using a WPF Datagrid and placed a textbox in all the cell templates.means my entire Row consists of all the textbox with data binded to that.Now when i select any row from the datagrid and hit ctrl+c,i want to copy entire row data to clipboard.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Text" >
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
             <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SAMPLETEXT}" />
       </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Tried using the below code but it is throwing empty data i.e not copying anything.I think this is because my complete Row consists of textbox.

```
private void DataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.C && (e.SystemKey == Key.LeftCtrl || e.SystemKey == Key.RightCtrl))
    {

        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dataGridTest);

    }
}
```

Please suggest me any better approach.
Thanks for reading.

---

**UPDATE**
Adding below line of code to DataGridTemplateColumn worked for me.

```
ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding SampleText}"
```

Comment: Have you tried tracing through the code to find what the values are on your if statement?

Comment: ya,my Selected row values are coming but it is not being copied to the clipboard

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pro-grammatically set values to [`Clipboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) using `Clipboard` class:

```
Clipboard.SetText("your data");
```

Extract data from the selected row, combine it in a `string` variable and assign that variable to the `Clipboard`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but this solution is posted for completeness and is missing the use of a suited DataGrid event method signature associated with the DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs.

Clipboard.SetText can be flaky, not grabbing/setting the clipboard all the time.

Set "FullRow" at the SelectionUnit mode for dataGrid called myDataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" SelectionUnit="FullRow"></DataGrid>
```

We have a method myDataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent that gets called for **each** row in the dataGrid to copy its contents to the clipboard. For example,for a datagrid with 10 rows this is called 10 times.

```
public int clipboardcalledcnt { get; set; } //CopyingRowClipboardContent invoked count
private void myDataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    PathInfo cellpath = new PathInfo(); //a custom class to hold path info
    string path = string.Empty;

DataGrid dgdataPaths = (DataGrid)sender;
int rowcnt = dgdataPaths.SelectedItems.Count;

cellpath = (PathInfo)e.Item;

path = "Row #"+ clipboardcalledcnt +" Len="+ cellpath.Length.ToString() + ", path=" + cellpath.Path;

e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();

if (clipboardcalledcnt == 0) //add header to clipboard paste
    e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(new DataGridClipboardCellContent("", null, "--- Clipboard Paste ---\t\t\n")); // \t cell divider, repeat (number of cells - 1)

clipboardcalledcnt++;
e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(new DataGridClipboardCellContent(path, null, path));

if (clipboardcalledcnt == rowcnt)
    clipboardcalledcnt = 0;
```

}